# How can I share membership between Azure Devops and Microsoft Teams?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

In our organisation, we're heavy users of Microsoft Teams and Azure Devops, and I'd like to use membership of a given team to drive membership of a given group within VSTS. Commonly, this could be for cross business virtual teams of stakeholders on a given product, where Microsoft Teams is good for pulling in the relevant people.

Is there any way to achieve this, or do I have to stick with manual processes and updating VSO accordingly, whenever responsibilities change within the organisation?

Comment: Are you using Azure AD?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes and no - we obviously have the Azure AD that comes with O365 (and therefore Microsoft Teams), and our VSO instance shares the same tenancy, I believe. We use a different domain for local log-on permissions, however...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated way of doing this. Internally at Microsoft we use security groups (SGs) to administer our Azure DevOps, but SGs are not the same as Office 365 groups in which Teams is based. You could write code to do this though.